# Windows Server 2008 Firewall alternative with IPS options?

Tags: untagged

What is good substitute for windows server 2008 firewall with some Intrusion Prevention System Options?

Comment: Sure. A Cisco router in front of a Windows Server 2008.

Comment: @mailq Normally I'd agree with you on the dupe, but the Server 2008 firewall is majorly different than the 2003 firewall that's discussed in many of those answers.

Comment: @MarkM Ok, noted and removed. But I can't revoke the vote (technically).

Comment: Could you be specific about what you want? Why are you looking for a substitute?

Answer (score 2):

Windows Firewall in Server 2008 and later does quite a bit more than application-specific rules. It does port-based rules, service-based rules, and it also can handle IP restrictions on any rules as well. It's quite robust, but still different than a typical hardware firewall or pf and netfiler. If you need something like a hardware firewall, use one on conjunction with your software firewall.

Comment: I don't have problem with the windows firewall, I'd like to know if there is an alternative.

Comment: @MatBanik Of course there are alternatives, many security companies sell them (Symantec, McAfee). Are they a good idea? No, probably not. Why would you want to replace a well-integrated and programmatically manageable piece of software with one that's less integrated and has the same functionality? Unless you have a specific need to replace the Windows Firewall, there's no good reason to.